# What's wrong with my dbconfig.properties file in Spring MVC?I run the projcet well but in JUnit it is wrong

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I run the project well.  Now I want to use JUnit to test my service.  It get wrong.  I try to change it to `utf-8` without BOM.  But it is still wrong.  Can anyone have a project JUnit injectiontest sample to service?
The exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [dbconfig.properties]
2015 22:20:18 ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@387a4e7] to prepare test instance [apptest.HelloWorldTest@3e5b3b80]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [dbconfig.properties] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Foreword content not allowed
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
```

My dbconfig.properties file is:

```
url:jdbc:mysql://**mydbip**:3306/testdb?Unicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
driverClassName:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
username:root
password:123456
```

Comment: An  even more accurate description for 前言中不允许有内容 in the log message , instead of 'Foreword content not allowed', would be 'Content is not allowed in prolog'. Weird locale settings for that inside log message alone

Comment: Show us your test and configuration setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test expects you provide the configuration via xml file.

> Loading **XML** bean definitions from class path resource
>   [dbconfig.**properties**]

However you are using a properties file, so the test must somehow be instructed to tell the difference.
Or you can simply try the XML version. How to do that is beyond the scope of this question as it needs all your configuration details.

Comment: it is strange that I can run the project but the JUnit test can not work.I will provide my configuration soon.